# How do I get custom variable, billing address, shipping address in Invoice using SOAP API of magento1.7?

Tags: magento-1.7, api, soap

I am using SOAP API in Magento 1.7

Its easy pretty to fetch Invoice details using invoice id.

But it provide billing_address_id and shipping_address_id only

How I can fetch corresponding addresses using above ids using SOAP API?

And one more question

I have tracking number from vendor saved in database associated to invoice id

How I can access this tracking number from SOAP API?

Answer (score 1):

When retrieving an invoice you already receive the id of the order in the member `parent_id`. Do an other call to the server and retrieve the order details using `salesOrderInfo`.
On the order object you should have the billing and shipping addresses as objects with type `salesOrderAddressEntity`.
For tracking numbers call the method `salesOrderShipmentList` and get a list of all order shipments (again using as parameter the `parent_id` field of the invoice). The result should be an array with objects of type `salesOrderShipmentEntity`. Each of these objects should have a member called `tracks` that is an array with elements with type `salesOrderShipmentTrackEntity` that contain the tracking number in the member `number`.